# PhoneGap merge folder not created

Tags: cordova

I have created a PhoneGap project as the steps in [Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

To avoid different code in various platforms, I found a good idea from the tutorial: **use "merge" folders.**

However, I found there was no "merge" folder at all in my PhoneGap project directory.

The screenshot is as below.

[image: Screenshot of my project]

Do I need to create the folder by myself? Or do I need do anything else to generate the "merge" folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merges folder was removed in 3.5.0

More info about this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6709

http://markmail.org/message/vqzzxnhk7yosmabj